# Scala running issue on eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala

I configured everthing within eclipse for scala. I create a snippet to show you the issue, i can't see in run options ***run as scala application***, i also tried to find my main class under ***build configuration*** option but i can't find it.

[image: screenshotaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]

How i can solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to run as scala application, you need to create Scala App and not class

In eclipse, package explorer
select project/src/package
right click
new>scala app

inform Name e.g. Test and click "finish"

select Test.scala
right click
"run as Scala Application"

see results in console window.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `class` with `object`.

You can even have it extend `Application` so it can look like:

```
object afaf extends Application {
    println("Done.")
}
```